# CSV vs. Parquet Files for Athena tables

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

We would like to run an experiment to determine whether our target/curated product should be stored in csv or parquet format through a series of queries (joins and aggregations). Other than just checking the execution time in Athena, are there other stats we can check in Athena?

I found the Explain button, but I am not familiar with database explain so I'm unsure what I should be looking for...

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Parquet or ORC, and make sure it is compressed. It will be both faster and cheaper, no question about it.

Follow these examples and you'll see for yourself: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Basically:

- **Amazon Athena charges based on data read from disk.** Compressed data will reduce the amount of data read from disk. Using a columnar file format will also greatly reduce the amount of disk access required.
- Columnar data formats are faster to query because it is 'intelligent' and allows data to be passed-over and never read from disk
- You can convert to Snappy-compressed Parquet format using a `CREATE TABLE AS` command -- see [Examples of CTAS queries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example-compression):

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
      format = 'Parquet',
      write_compression = 'SNAPPY')
AS SELECT *
FROM old_table;
```